# What to do with [google-docs], [google-drive], [google-drive-file-stream] and [google-drive-for-desktop]

Tags: discussion, tags

[google-docs](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-docs) has 134 questions. Several years ago, "Google Docs" was the name of what currently is called "Google Drive". See [What to do with "Opening local document files in Google Docs" from 2009](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14971/152004) for details.

[google-drive-for-desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-for-desktop) has 1 question. This tag has no wiki.

[google-drive-file-stream](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-file-stream) has 42 questions. According to its tag wiki, this tag should be used for the Google Drive clients launched in 2017 and the current client.

[google-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-drive) has 541 questions. According to its tag wiki, this tag should be used for the Google Drive client that was discontinued in 2017. [[google-drive] created:2017..2023 is:question](https://superuser.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-drive%5D+created%3A2017..2023+is%3Aquestion) returns 256 questions posted since 2017 with this tag which are very unlikely that a high percentage of them be about the discontinued client. Most of the new questions related to Google Drive use this tag instead of the one mentioned above.

If the clean-up might not be worth it, then I think that `google-drive-file-system` should be a synonym for `google-drive`. What do you think?

---

[google-backup-and-sync](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-backup-and-sync) has 28 questions. It hasn't tag wiki. According to the tag wiki of [google-drive-file-stream](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-file-stream), the  [google-backup-and-sync](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-backup-and-sync) should be a synonym of [google-drive-file-stream](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-file-stream).

---

Additionally to the above, another situation tag used sometimes together with the tags mentioned above is the following:

[google-sync](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-sync) has 65 questions. It hasn't tag wiki. According to [What is Google Sync](https://support.google.com/a/answer/135937?)

> Google Sync uses Microsoft Exchange ActiveSync 12.1 to let users synchronize their work or school mail, contacts, and calendars to their mobile devices.

[google-sync](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-sync) is used on some questions about Google Drive, some of them together with [google-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-drive), [google-backup-and-sync](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-backup-and-sync),  [google-photos](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-photos), [google-chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome), among other usually unrelated tags, which doesn't match with the above description of Google Sync.

Some of the expected tags to be used in questions related to Google Sync are [microsoft-outlook](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-outlook), [apple-mail](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/apple-mail),  [exchange](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/exchange), [calendar](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/calendar), and similar tags.

NOTE: Google recommends organizations stop using Google Sync in favor of other more secure options as it doesn't support OAuth2 (the source of this is the previous link).

It might be needed to add a tag wiki to [google-sync](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-sync) and do some retag / clean-up.

---

Related

- [Add tag for drive-file-stream and for google-backup-and-sync](https://meta.superuser.com/q/13234/152004)

---

Recent questions with [google-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-drive) that should be retagged (Most recent first)

- [Google Drive was hacked with Ransomware](https://superuser.com/q/1778121/152004)
- [How to copy text from Google Drive webpage?](https://superuser.com/q/1777488/152004)
- [Google Drive file icons broken and I cannot download files](https://superuser.com/q/1777428/152004)
- https://superuser.com/q/1758723/152004

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion, let's do a tag-clean up:

1. Rename [google-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-drive) to `google-drive-2012`. The version of the deprecated Google Drive client that the tag excerpt makes reference it's very like that was the very first one. As Google Drive was launched in 2012 I think that it makes sense to add the year to this tag name.
2. Create `google-drive` by editing the tags of the following questions (just as starting point):

   - [How to copy text from Google Drive webpage?](https://superuser.com/q/1777488/152004)
   - [Google Drive file icons broken and I cannot download files](https://superuser.com/q/1777428/152004)

   The idea is to use this tag for questions about Google Drive on the Web that are on-topic in Super User. Some questions are related to networking issues (VPN, etc.), and others are about an issue with a web browser.
3. Delete [google-drive-for-desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-for-desktop).
4. Rename [google-drive-file-strean](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-file-strean) to `google-drive-for-desktop` as the current name of the Google Drive installable client is "Google Drive for Desktop". Google Drive File Stream was renamed this way.
5. Create `google-docs-2006` (The first "version" of "Google Docs" was launched in 2006) by adding this tag to:

   - [Google Docs drawings to Visio](https://superuser.com/q/422211/152004)
   - [Excel lookup data from google docs spread sheet](https://superuser.com/q/403821/152004)
6. Retag the following questions, replace [google-docs](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-docs) with `google-docs-2006` in the 36 questions returned by [created:..2012-03 [google-docs] is:question closed:0](https://superuser.com/search?q=created%3A..2012-03%20%5Bgoogle-docs%5D%20is%3Aquestion%20closed%3A0).
7. Review [google-sync](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-sync). When this is appropriate, replace this tag with the appropriate tags mentioned above.
8. Leave as is [google-backup-and-sync](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-backup-and-sync).